# A combinatorial identity $\sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{m}{n} \binom{2n}{m+n} 2^{-2n} = 1$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How to prove $\sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{m}{n} \binom{2n}{m+n} 2^{-2n} = 1$.
It is from Stochastic Processes. We can regard $\binom{2n}{m+n} 2^{-2n}$ as probability of one get $2m$ on the $2n$th step in a simple random walk.
But homework is to use some method to directly prove this formula without combinatorial background. How can I make it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried by rewriting the given summation as $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{m}{m+n} \binom{2m+2n}{2m+n} 2^{-(m+n)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2m}{n!} (2m+2n-1) \cdots (2m+n+1) \, 2^{-(m+n)} $$ In order to make it simple, I think I have made it more messy.

Comment: Maybe this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416531/infinite-sum-generalising-catalan-generating-function?noredirect=1 helps.